# About Google Drive's "state parameter"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

My App for Google Drive is by Google Script.
When I select files in Drive and then call my App, an official "state parameter" will be sent into my App for further digestion. However, the official document is not clear enough for its setting. I need to collect its info from different area like Google I/O video and examples. Is there a good site to introduce it?
Official Site: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open

Especially, for the process, User select files in a Active folder => Run App => App save back files to Active Folder ... but this is the problem. How can I know which is the active folder through the state parameter? Any suitable command?

N.B. It is meaningless to use MyFile.getFolders() command, since one file can belong to several folders, and I cannot distinguish which one is "Active" folder.

Comment: This question is too vague without some solid code or results to explain your problem. Try adding more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation shows some code that gets the id after the file is picked from a Google Drive:

```
// A simple callback implementation.
function pickerCallback(data) {
  if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
    alert('The user selected: ' + fileId);
  }
}
```